# Springboot ReactJS package

Tags: reactjs, package, spring-boot-starter

I am trying to package the springboot and reactjs and deploy it to tomcat 9. My problem is when I accessing my frontend, it showing a blank page. Is there anyone knows this?

pom.xml
`
com.github.eirslett
frontend-maven-plugin
1.14.2

v18.17.1
9.6.7
src/main/client
target/classes/static




Install node and npm

install-node-and-npm

generate-resources

```
                </execution>
                <!--Running npm install-->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--Build our production version-->
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--Build our production version-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-frontend-build-into-springboot</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/client/dist</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>`
```

client forwarder
`@Controller
public class ClientForwarderController {

```
@RequestMapping("/{path:[^\\.]+}/**")
public String forward() {
    return "forward:/";
}`
```

I want to merge the springboot and reactjs in one build.